# Code compiling but output is previous code version?

Tags: c++, ide

I am working with Visual Studio IDE. The code will compile with no errors. However any changes I made will not be reflected in the latest build.

I compiled with gcc and the changes were reflected in the build. However when I restart Visual Studio it still builds a previous version

for example if I change the code to read:
cout << "PLACEHOLDER syntactically correct program" << endl;

It will still output the previous build:
"syntactically correct program"

EDIT: updating Visual Studio seemed to do the trick

Comment: Possibly clean the project and rebuild otherwise clean and restart MSVC.

Comment: Also look at the date & time on the generated executable.

Comment: If you want to really test that changes aren't getting implemented: put some syntactically *incorrect* program on purpose. If the compiler is truly compiling your code, you will get an error.